Minimising quadratic function subject to linear equality constraints.
The Problem
At a higher level, I am trying to minimise a function that looks a bit like this
\begin{equation}
(x_2-x_1+c_1)^2 + (x_3-x_2+c_2)^2 + ...
\end{equation}
Subject to the constraint that $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$, $x_4+x_5+x_6=0$, ...
What I have tried
I have used Lagrange multipliers, and found all the derivatives and what they need to be. In doing so I have essentially reduced my problem to a pair of matrix equations. They are
\begin{equation}
Ax+\lambda=c \\
\Lambda x=0
\end{equation}
I have that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, $x$ and $\lambda$ are my unknown vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$, $c$ is a constant vector from $\mathbb{R}^n$. And finally $\Lambda$ is an $m\times n$ matrix.
My main goal is to solve for $x$. However, I don't know what $\lambda$ is. I do know that it only depends on $m$ parameters, and that there is enough information in the $\Lambda x=0$ equation to uniquely determine $\lambda$.
In my specific case (though I am hopeing for something more general) I have that $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \lambda_1, \lambda_1, \lambda_2, ...)^T$ and that
\begin{equation}
\Lambda = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ... \\
...
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
I could easily rewrite the entire problem by simply extending $x$ to contain all the missing values of $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ...$ and then slightly changing $A$ so it is some sort of block matrix. And I am happy to do this if its the best option. But $A$ has some really nice properties and I can invert it just fine alone, I know there do exist nice rules that let us invert block matrices and this is likely what I will end up doing. Just hopping someone has a better solution that might be a bit cleaner.

It might be what NN2 is trying to say, but why not use each constraint to isolate one variable and inject its expression into the objective? That way, you end up with an unconstrained quadratic problem.
